# javascript code to check for a specific number in multi level arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi recently i was doing some homework and had to find 0 in a multi level array with only javascript so im leaving this code here if someone needs it :)

```
var myArray = [
        [2, 0, 10, 100],
        [3, 4, 5, 0, 10, 0],
        [11, 12, 11, 0, 10, 12, 0, 15, 0, 10, 0]
    ]; // ugnjezdeni nizovi 

    var counter = 0;
    console.log(myArray, myArray[0].length, myArray[1].length, myArray[2].length);
    var arrayLenght1 = myArray[0].length;
    var arrayLenght2 = myArray[1].length;
    var arrayLenght3 = myArray[2].length;
    console.log(arrayLenght1, arrayLenght2, arrayLenght3);

    for (var iterator = 0; iterator <= myArray[0].length; iterator++) {
        //   console.log("this is the current value " + iterator); mkay

        if (myArray[0][iterator] == 0) {
            counter = counter + 1;
            console.log("this is the count after a row 1 is passed " + counter);
        }

    }
    for (var iterator = 0; iterator <= myArray[1].length; iterator++) {
        if (myArray[1][iterator] == 0) {
            counter = counter + 1;
            console.log("this is the count after a row 2 is passed " + counter);
        }
    }
    for (var iterator = 0; iterator <= myArray[2].length; iterator++) {
        if (myArray[2][iterator] == 0) {
            counter = counter + 1;
            console.log("this is the count after a row 3 is passed " + counter);
        }
    }

    console.log("this is the final count after all the rows have been checked for 0 = " + counter);
```

actual result is you get the number of 0 in the specified rows in a variable.

Comment: If you are just leaving this here for information you should clearly define the problem and then write an answer to it below.

Comment: this is a place for questions and answers. If you want to put the solution for a commom problem, you should first ask how to to solve this commom problem, then answer your question with the solution

Comment: This is a statement, not a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to count number of zeros, there are more efficient ways of doing that

```js
var myArray = [
    [2, 0, 10, 100],
    [3, 4, 5, 0, 10, 0],
    [11, 12, 11, 0, 10, 12, 0, 15, 0, 10, 0]
];

myArray.map((row, rowNumber) => console.log(`number of zeros in row ${rowNumber}:`, row.filter(element => element === 0).length))
```

if you want to have a total of zeros in all rows prior you could do that

```js
var myArray = [
    [2, 0, 10, 100],
    [3, 4, 5, 0, 10, 0],
    [11, 12, 11, 0, 10, 12, 0, 15, 0, 10, 0]
];

const [row1, row2, row3] = myArray.map((row, rowNumber) => row.filter(element => element === 0).length)

console.log(row1);
console.log(row1+row2);
console.log(row1+row2+row3);
```